# Where can i find list of miui, oppo permissions

Tags: android, miui, oppo

Xioami, Oppo and some other vendors have custom android permission like.

```java
// from https://github.com/KashaMalaga/XiaomiMiBand/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="miui.permission.BLE_IMMEDIATE_ALERT"/>
```

Where are these permission documented? also which of these permissions are implicitly granted.

For my current usecase i need to get show on lock screen, and autostart permission for miui and equivalent permission for other vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these device specific permission at referred url. These permissions included Android Native permissions as well.

--> Go to URL

--> Click on Devices menu from top bar

--> Select Device

--> Select Permissions properties.

URL : https://census.tsyrklevich.net/devices

Comment: This link provides information for older devices only(upto android 6 for xioami), where can i find updated information?